# The constructor InterstitialAd

Tags: java, android, admob

I am trying to integrate InterstitialAd in one of my application's fragment. I am following official site for it, but if I input code like below that its giving me error like The constructor InterstitialAd(AuthorListFragment) is undefined

```
The constructor InterstitialAd(MyListFragment) is undefined
```

My complete code is like below.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group,Bundle savedState){
    super.onCreateView(inflater,group,savedState);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,null);


    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("7C77ADF1D83FA8B87C0481D6748FA4DB")
    .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
          .addTestDevice("7C77ADF1D83FA8B87C0481D6748FA4DB")
          .build();
          mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

What I am missing in this ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group,Bundle savedState){
    super.onCreateView(inflater,group,savedState);

   //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,null);
   // take this to end

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("7C77ADF1D83FA8B87C0481D6748FA4DB")
    .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
          .addTestDevice("7C77ADF1D83FA8B87C0481D6748FA4DB")
          .build();
          mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,null);

}
```

Comment: please tick mark and vote up instead of saying thanks.